# Create new folder named with a specified file name in Automator

Tags: automator

I want to create a new folder named with the filename of the file used for the input.

Example:

If I use my new service with the file "test (test).jpg" I want to automatically create a folder named "test (test)".

Answer (score 2):

To do this with regular Automator actions it gets a bit convoluted, since you need to save the original input, get the name, make the folder, get the original input back, etc.  You can use a **Run AppleScript** action to do most of that in one go, although it depends on what you are wanting to do with the original input and created folder paths.

The following **Run AppleScript** action will create new folders with the name of the input items (note that a service can pass multiple items), and just passes the original input on.  The new folders are created in the same parent folder - no error handling (duplicate names, etc) is performed:

```
on run {input, parameters} -- make new folders from base file names

    set output to {}

    repeat with anItem in the input -- step through each item in the input

        set anItem to anItem as text
        tell application "System Events" to tell disk item anItem
            set theContainer to path of container
            set {theName, theExtension} to {name, name extension}
        end tell
        if theExtension is in {missing value, ""} then
            set theExtension to ""
        else
            set theExtension to "." & theExtension
        end if
        set theName to text 1 thru -((count theExtension) + 1) of theName -- the name part

        tell application "Finder"
            make new folder at folder theContainer with properties {name:theName}
            set end of output to result as alias
        end tell
    end repeat

    return input -- or output
end run
```