# moving one folder to another folder - applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to move a user-selected folder to another folder, but I don't get it: whenever I look it up, it looks too complicated, even though I know it's not supposed to be.

Here's the code I have so far - please help:

```applescript
choose folder with prompt "Select folder:"

on open of finderObject

  tell application "Finder" to move (finderObject) to folder "Library:Application Support"

end open

end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220379/applescript-create-new-folder-from-file-name-and-move-file-into-that-folder?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

First off, you have to assign the chosen folder to a variable.
Also, many special folders in the OSX file structure have special names to get their paths, including the library and the application support folders. So, your script can simply be:

```
set finderObject to choose folder with prompt "Select folder:"
tell app "Finder" to move finderObject to folder (path to Application Support folder from local domain as string)
```

However, that is the root level Library folder. I suspect you will want to use the Application Support folder in the ~/ user domain. For that, change the "from local domain" to "from user domain".

Comment: what if i want to put it in a folder within a folder within application support

Comment: ((path to Application Support folder from local domain as string) & "MyFolder:")    (For archive reasons, please accept the answer.)

Comment: and can you give another example like if i wanted to put it in application support/application/application version/version Thanks

Comment: ((path to Application Support folder from local domain as string) & "application:application version:version:")